# How to work with association with user and a given record in mongo Db using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new in NodeJs and I have a backend in Node that uses Mongo Db as database. I can do CRUD operations in my backend the problem is that when I do a GET to all my movies this is the response

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Movies list found!!!",
    "data": {
        "movies": [
            {
                "id": "5b72b2663911d82018cb81c3",
                "name": "Iron Man",
                "released_on": "2018-05-12T00:00:00.000Z"
            }      
        ]
    }
}
```

In the case above I dont know what user created the movie so I wanted something like this:

```
 {
        "status": "success",
        "message": "Movies list found!!!",
        "data": {
            "movies": [
                {
                    "id": "5b72b2663911d82018cb81c3",
                    "name": "Iron Man",                 
                    "released_on": "2018-05-12T00:00:00.000Z"
                    "creating_user" : [
                      //informations regarding the user who created the movie in the db
                   ]
                }      
            ]
        }
    }
```

For that I have the follwing models:

**UserModel**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;

//Define a schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    }
});
// hash user password before saving into database
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, saltRounds);
    next();
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**Movie Model**

```
const User = require("../models/users")
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//Define a schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const MovieSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
    },
    released_on: {
        type: Date,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    creating_user:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Movie', MovieSchema)
```

**This is my controller**

```
const movieModel = require('../models/movies');
const usersModel = require('../models/users');
module.exports = {

  create: function (req, res, next) {
    movieModel.create({ name: req.body.name, released_on: req.body.released_on, creating_user: "DONT KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE" }, function (err, result) {
      if (err)
        next(err);
      else
        res.json({ status: "success", message: "Movie added successfully!!!", data: null });

    });
  },
}
```

So in summary my question is, what should I put in my controller in order to save the user infromation alongside the movie information.

Answer (score 0):

your need to put userId (mongo _id of user) in creating_user field while creating movie.

```
const movieModel = require('../models/movies');
const usersModel = require('../models/users');
module.exports = {

  create: function (req, res, next) {
    let userId=//get userId from req or auth token if you are using jwt
    movieModel.create({ name: req.body.name, released_on: 
        req.body.released_on, creating_user: userId }, function (err, result) {
      if (err)
        next(err);
      else
        res.json({ status: "success", message: "Movie added successfully!!!", data: null });

    });
  },
}
```

and when you will get all the movie list then you will have to populate creating_user so that you can get records of user:

```
  movieModel.find({}).populate('creating_user')
   .exec(function (err, item) {
    //do your stuff here
    });
```

Comment: Can you put an example on how to obtain the userId from the auth token? I am using jwt in this case

Comment: ok while creating jwt token you might be putting user object or user details in that. you can decode in a middle-ware while you are verifying the token  `jwt.verify(token, function(err, decoded) { req.user=decoded});` then you can get user object in every api req passing through this middle-ware

Comment: or if you have userId in the frontend you can pass userId in the req.body of the api. and then get it in the api as `let userId= req.body.userId` .